Spark writing to Managed instance tables no longer working when upgrading to Spark 3.3.0
When we upgraded  from spark 3.2 to 3.3, notebooks which are writing back to managed instanced SQL tables are failing.
We also applied the spark-mssql-connector_2.12-1.2.0.jar.
Anyone has faced the same issue and the solution for it?
Thanks
the error:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last) Cell In [13], line 12      1 PARENT_SALES_CASTED_df.write \      2   .format("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.spark") \      3   .option("url", url_SALES_DTM) \      4   .option("user", sqluser) \      5   .option("password", password) \      6   .option("dbTable", "EU.FACT_PARENT_SALES_FASM") \      7   .option("keepIdentity", False) \      8   .option("schemaCheckEnabled", False) \      9   .option("batchsize", 100000) \     10   .option("truncate", True) \     11   .mode("overwrite") ---> 12   .save() File /opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py:966, in DataFrameWriter.save(self, path, format, mode, partitionBy, **options)    964     self.format(format)    965 if path is None:--> 966     self._jwrite.save()    967 else:    968     self._jwrite.save(path) File ~/cluster-env/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py:1321, in JavaMember.call(self, *args)   1315 command = proto.CALL_COMMAND_NAME +\   1316     self.command_header +\   1317     args_command +\   1318     proto.END_COMMAND_PART   1320 answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)-> 1321 return_value = get_return_value(   1322     answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)   1324 for temp_arg in temp_args:   1325     temp_arg._detach() File /opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py:190, in capture_sql_exception..deco(*a, **kw)    188 def deco(*a: Any, **kw: Any) -> Any:    189     try:--> 190         return f(*a, **kw)    191     except Py4JJavaError as e:    192         converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception) File ~/cluster-env/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/py4j/protocol.py:326, in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)    324 value = OUTPUT_CONVERTER[type](answer[2:], gateway_client)    325 if answer[1] == REFERENCE_TYPE:--> 326     raise Py4JJavaError(    327         "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".    328         format(target_id, ".", name), value)    329 else:    330     raise Py4JError(    331         "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}. Trace:\n{3}\n".    332         format(target_id, ".", name, value)) Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o4091.save. : java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$.createConnectionFactory(Lorg/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/jdbc/JDBCOptions;)Lscala/Function0;    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.spark.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:56)  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.run(SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.scala:47)     at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:75)    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:73)   at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.executeCollect(commands.scala:84)     at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.$anonfun$applyOrElse$1(QueryExecution.scala:152)     at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$6(SQLExecution.scala:111)   at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:183)   at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:97)    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:779)     at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:66)   at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:152)    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:145)    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDownWithPruning$1(TreeNode.scala:584)     at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:176)    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDownWithPruning(TreeNode.scala:584)    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:31)     at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning(AnalysisHelper.scala:267)    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning$(AnalysisHelper.scala:263)   at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:31)   at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:31)   at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:560)   at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.eagerlyExecuteCommands(QueryExecution.scala:145)   at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:129)   at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted(QueryExecution.scala:123)  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertCommandExecuted(QueryExecution.scala:183)    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:901)   at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:415)   at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveInternal(DataFrameWriter.scala:382)     at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:249)     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)     at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)   at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)     at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)   at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Dispose d’un menu contextuel

This is the error we are getting.

Can you paste the full error message as text into your question?

I have added the error text


An error occurred while calling o4091.save. :
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$.createConnectionFactory

A NoSuchMethodError typically means that you've got the wrong version of some JAR file loaded.  The code was compiled against a version that has the method, but at runtime you've got some other version that doesn't.

we are using this one: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.azure/spark-mssql-connector_2.12/1.2.0. Is this the correct one or we need another?

See https://github.com/microsoft/sql-spark-connector?tab=readme-ov-file#apache-spark-connector-for-sql-server-and-azure-sql : "Spark 3.3.x compatible connector com.microsoft.azure:spark-mssql-connector_2.12:1.3.0  2.12"

But the 3.0 is still in beta right? https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.azure/spark-mssql-connector_2.12/1.3.0-BETA

Perhaps Microsoft should comment why it doesnt support 3.3 and later Spark versions.
